# How to send a custom FacesMessage to page when the clientId is not actually present

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF 2.2 on Glassfish 4.

I want to send messages to `<h:message .../>` tag.

For my below login page, I want to send a custom `FacesMessage` on login failure to clientId `login-error` from my `UserBean`.

My `login.xhtml`:

```
<h:form id="login-form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><h:outputLabel value="Username" for="username" /></td>
            <td><h:inputText id="username" value="#{userBean.username}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h:outputLabel value="Password" for="password" /></td>
            <td><h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{userBean.password}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{userBean.login()}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <h:message for="login-error" errorClass="err" />
    </div>
</h:form>
```

My `UserBean`:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
    . . .

    public String login() {
        if (validate(username, password)) {
            return "/success?faces-redirect=true";
        }
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String msgText = "Username or Password is incorrect";
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msgText, msgText);
        ctx.addMessage("login-error", msg );
        return "";
    }

}
```

I get the below messages in server console:

```
2017-04-14T21:43:02.298+0530|Warning: Unable to find component with ID login-error in view.
2017-04-14T21:43:04.923+0530|Warning: Unable to find component with ID login-error in view.
2017-04-14T21:43:04.923+0530|Info: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=login-error[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(Username or Password is incorrect), detail=(Username or Password is incorrect)]
```

I've also tried using clientId `login-form:login-error` which also didn't work.

So, my question is how to send a custom FacesMessage to page when the clientId is actually not present? Is my approach incorrect?

I know I can use `<h:messages />` instead but I don't want to use it.

Comment: Just send it to 'username' and change the `h:message for` also to 'username'. That is how it works in jsf

Comment: or create a global message (not bound to a component) and use `h:messages` with the `globalOnly` attribute.

Comment: See also the description for the `for` attribute of `h:message`: "Client identifier of the component for which to display messages."

Comment: @JasperdeVries - Agree that works. But as I mentioned I want to display only *specific* messages that I want. As such, `<h:messages globalOnly="true"/>` gets all kinds of global messages.

Comment: Or send it to the form, or whatever. And please leave the java, java-ee and java-ee7 and jsf2.2 tags off, these are not related to your problem (even though you are using them, but you are using css to and xhtml and electricity and a computer and cpu, but these are not related either to the actual problem